# UIImagePickerController cancel button not working when compressing video

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

My app provides a video upload function. But after selecting the video, UIImagePickerController will perform video compression. At this time, clicking the Cancel button will not interrupt the compression process. Is there a way to solve this problem? Reference Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBSAv.png

system is iOS 12.1

```
 let vc = UIImagePickerController()
 vc.sourceType = .photoLibrary
 vc.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
 vc.delegate = self
 navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
//when compressing video left button is not responding
```

Comment: i think, uiimagepicker does not allow this. you have to use custom picker

Answer (score 0):

You can't interrupt the systems `UIImagePickerController` video compression.

What you can do if you need this functionality is initialize the `UIImagePickerController` with passthrough preset like this:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *))
    picker.videoExportPreset = AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough;
```

Then you can fully manage compression with something like `SDAVAssetExportSession` (that is a more feature-complete version of systems `AVAssetExportSession`) and a modal view with a progress indicator and a cancel button that call `cancelExport` of your `exportSession` instance.